# C++ WinSock2 Errors

Tags: c++, winsock2

Yesterday I've tried to make a socket server in C++, but I get errors upon compiling.
The errors:

Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_socket@12     referenced in function "public: static unsigned long __cdecl Env::GetSocket(void)" (?GetSocket@Env@@SAKXZ)   C:\Users\JoshuaTha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HabboV5\HabboV5\Network.obj    HabboV5

Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_listen@8 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Network::Start(void)" (?Start@Network@@QAEXXZ)    C:\Users\JoshuaTha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HabboV5\HabboV5\Network.obj    HabboV5

Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_htons@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Network::Start(void)" (?Start@Network@@QAEXXZ) C:\Users\JoshuaTha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HabboV5\HabboV5\Network.obj    HabboV5

Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_bind@12 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Network::Start(void)" (?Start@Network@@QAEXXZ) C:\Users\JoshuaTha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HabboV5\HabboV5\Network.obj    HabboV5

Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class Network * Env::Network" (?Network@Env@@2PAV0@A) C:\Users\JoshuaTha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HabboV5\HabboV5\HabboV5.obj    HabboV5

Error   7   error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals   C:\Users\JoshuaTha\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HabboV5\Debug\HabboV5.exe  HabboV5

My main .cpp class:

```
// HabboV5.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Env.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
cout.write("hi", 2);
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

Env::Network = new Network();
Env::Network->Start();

while (1)
{
    char input[256];
    cin.getline(input, 256);
}
}
```

Network.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <WinSock2.h>

class Network
{
private:
    SOCKET socket;
public:
    Network(void);
    void Start();
};
```

Network.cpp:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Network.h"
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include "Env.h"

Network::Network(void)
{
}

void Network::Start()
{
    this->socket = Env::GetSocket();

    SOCKADDR_IN sInformation;

    sInformation.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sInformation.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sInformation.sin_port = htons(30000);

    bind(this->socket, (SOCKADDR*) (&sInformation), sizeof(sInformation));
    listen(this->socket, 10);
}
```

Env.h:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Network.h"
#include <WinSock2.h>

class Env
{
public:
    static Network* Network;

    static DWORD GetSocket()
    {
        return socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    }
};
```

Comment: you didn't include an implib for the DLLs defining the socket stuff. Look msdn what libs ho with winsock2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the linker options (on the project right-click, linker, input) you need add `wsock32.lib` or `ws2_32.lib` to the list of input files.

Comment: I don't really know the difference, but wsock32.lib didn't work for me as the linker issue still happened with getaddrinfo and freeaddrinfo. Using ws2_32.lib did work right away